# Error Sort in Python 3.x : TypeError: must use keyword argument for key function

Tags: python

In python 2.x SORT worked well when I passed a function.
Switched to python 3.x .. sort has changed, but I did not understand how I have to modify the code to make it work also in python 3.
If I do not pass a function, everything works, but when I pass a function, I get the error: TypeError: must use keyword argument for key function

How should I change ....

```
A = [8, 89]
A = [str(c) for c in A]
def my_cmp(a,b):
    return cmp(int(b+a), int(a+b))
A.sort(my_cmp)
print(A)
```

Comment: You should use `key=my_cmp` and `my_cmp` expects one argument, but what is `cmp`? Please provide a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: cmp is not a valid function in Python 3. It was, in Python 2, but not anymore

Comment: I think his cmp returns string that is higher when converted to int(first + second), but he uses two arguments instead of one as you mention.

Comment: @Austin seems like a Minimal, complete, verifiable example to me, what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [cmp](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#cmp) is not a valid built-in function in Python 3 anymore, but you can emulate it.
2. [sort](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=sort#list.sort) works differently in Python 3, but you can use [cmp_to_key](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) to translate old Python 2 style sorts. You have to import [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#module-functools) to use `cmp_to_key`.

> The functools.cmp_to_key() utility is available to convert a 2.x style cmp function to a key function.

3. You have to use `key` keyword argument in Python 3 sort method

Here's an example implementation:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key   # required for cmp_to_key

def cmp(v1, v2):                   # emulate cmp from Python 2
    if (v1 < v2):
        return -1
    elif (v1 == v2):
        return 0
    elif (v1 > v2):
        return 1

A = [8, 89]
A = [str(c) for c in A]

def my_cmp(a, b):
    return cmp(int(b + a), int(a + b))

A.sort(key = cmp_to_key(my_cmp))   # use cmp_to_key to emulate Python 2 behavior
print(A)
```

Output is exactly the same as Python 2 output:

```
['89', '8']
```